Heating baseboards on a floor that's not level
I'm working withe a 200-year old house, and the top floor has no heating. I want to install heating baseboards and tie in to the rest of the hydronic system. However, the whole house settled 200 years ago and is not moving anymore, but the floors are out of level: as in 3" every 10'. So I can either install baseboards level, which would look awful in contrast with the floor, or I can install the baseboards following the floor, but risk trapping air. What is done in these cases? Follow the floor and install air bleeders everywhere? Install baseboards level and let the ugly be?

could you build a cover over them that still lets the air through, with access hatches for the valves?

@ratchetfreak It's an interesting idea, I'd have to see if they sell covers big enough.

Air will rise to the highest point. The system should have bleeders installed at the highest points of each heater or a minimum of highest point on each floor.
They are necessary when the system is first started up and it's usually good practice to bleed each floor or heater every year before cold season.
Once air is bled out of the system it doesn't matter that things are not level.
